# Perl Hashes: Using key/value pairs from external text file

Tags: file, perl, hash

I am trying to to create a hash which draws its key/value pairs from a separate text file on my server.

When I manually enter key/value pairs into a hash inside my perl script like in the example below, the hash works perfectly when I call it later on:

```
# Initialize hash 
my %format_key = ('SGBK', 'PRINT', 'SGDVD', 'VIDEO');

# Call hash (this is much later in the program)
$item_format = $format_key{$fields[2]};
```

When I save those exact same arguments to a text file, and then read in that file, save the contents to a scalar variable, and assign that variable to the arguments in the hash, the hash does not function.  Here is what I have done:

```
# Open file path saved in $format_key_file and save contents to $output
open(my $fh, '<', $format_key_file) or die "Could not read from $format_key_file, program halting."; {
 local $/;
 $output = <$fh>;
 }
 close($fh);

my %format_key = $output;

 # Call hash (this is much later in the program)
    $item_format = $format_key{$fields[2]};
```

I'm completely stumped.  I suppose I can just manually enter all of my hash arguments into the script itself, but there will be lots of these and I would prefer to have them saved in a file for ease of updating down the road.

Comment: The `$output` is a string with all of the file (even newlines included).  That won't make `%format_key` very happy and is different from what you do "manually."  What is the format of the file?

Comment: If you can choose in which format to store these things in the file see answer by @Grinnz for some options, where the most reasonable ones are presented in sample code. But if the file is given  then my question above stands: what is the format of that file?  (Unless it _is_ one of options in the answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read from the file, you get a string (or multiple strings, if you read line-by-line). The Perl parser only parses source code passed to the Perl interpreter, not anything you read from files or elsewhere. You can use the [eval](https://perldoc.pl/functions/eval) function to evaluate arbitrary strings like this as perl code and return the result of the last expression (in this case, a list of strings), but string eval is dangerous because it can run any code; if you accidentally read a file containing `system 'rm -rf ~/*'` you have a problem.

A better option is to store your data in a known serialization format. A common format used for such things is [JSON](https://json.org/), because it maps neatly to Perl data structures, but you can also just store your strings as lines (without Perl syntax like quoting) for a simple case like this. There are any number of other options like YAML, or even XML, but they are harder to decode; and binary formats like Storable, Sereal, and CBOR, but they are not human-readable so can only be interacted with by your code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::MaybeXS;
# if you store it as JSON: {"SGBK":"PRINT","SGDVD":"VIDEO"}
my %format_key = %{decode_json($output)};
# or from an even-sized array: ["SGBK","PRINT","SGDVD","VIDEO"]
my %format_key = @{decode_json($output)};

# if you store it as one value per line
my %format_key = split /\n/, $output;
```